# Error in using sklearn's GridSearchCV on Word2Vec

Tags: python, scikit-learn, word2vec, gensim, gridsearchcv

I am using the sklearn_api of gensim to create an estimator for a Word2vec model to pass it to sklearn's gridsearch . My code is as follows :

```
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

s_obj = W2VTransformer(size=100,min_count=1,window=5)

parameters = {'size':(100,150,200),'min_count':(1,2,4),'alpha':(0.025,0.015)}

s_model = GridSearchCV(s_obj,parameters,cv=2)
s_model.fit(sentences)

print(s_model.best_params_)
```

Running the above code, I get the following error:

```
"If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator W2VTransformer(alpha=0.025, batch_words=10000, cbow_mean=1,
               hashfxn=<built-in function hash>, hs=0, iter=5,
               max_vocab_size=None, min_alpha=0.0001, min_count=1, negative=5,
               null_word=0, sample=0.001, seed=1, sg=0, size=100,
               sorted_vocab=1, trim_rule=None, window=5, workers=3) does not."
```

I do not know how to resolve this. I tried using `scoring='accuracy'` or `scoring='hamming'` but they don't seem to work either.

Can someone please help me get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, make_scorer

s_model = GridSearchCV(s_obj,parameters,cv=2, scoring=make_scorer(accuracy_score))
```

Comment: Tried it and getting the following error :" ValueError: scoring value <function accuracy_score at 0x000001FDA62A6558> looks like it is a metric function rather than a scorer. A scorer should require an estimator as its first parameter. Please use `make_scorer` to convert a metric to a scorer."

Comment: Try it like this, with make_scorer

Comment: Sadly , that doesn't work either . It gives me an error " _score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true' " . Perhaps gridsearch can just not be applied to gensim's Word2vec ?

Comment: I don't think, it has a predict method. so, you will have next error. Gridsearch is to predict, get a score, and decide the best.

Comment: Oh okay . So , do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need all the functionality of GridSearchCV i.e. fit, K-Fold.

So you simply write a custom function to try all the different options and see which gives the best score.

**First thing**

 You will need to define your score. It is what you are actually looking for
*e.g. maybe the ratio of dimensions in vector and the word count*.

```py
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
import itertools

def  score_func(word, vector):
    #Define what you want to measure e.g. Ratio of Vector's dim and Word count etc.
    # I am returning a constant for demonstration
    return 1.0
```

**Then**

 We can simply loop on all the parm combination to get the best one

```py
parm_dict = {'size':(100,150,200),'min_count':(1,2,4),'alpha':(0.025,0.015)}

def cust_param_search(parm_dict):
    score_best, parm_best = 0,()
    s_obj = W2VTransformer(size=100,min_count=1,window=5)
    size, min_count, alpha = [tup for k,tup in parm_dict.items()] # Individual parm tuples

    parm_combo =    list(itertools.product(size, min_count, alpha)) # Create all combinations

    for parms in parm_combo:
        s, m , a = parms

        s_obj = W2VTransformer(size=s,min_count=m,window=5, alpha = a)
        ##Get other stuff to call the score function
        word, vector = "Hello",["H","L","O"] #Dummy parameters
        score = score_func(word, vector)

        if score > score_best:
            score_best = score
            parm_best = parms
    print("Best score -",score_best, "Best parms - ",parm_best)

cust_param_search(parm_dict)
```